# Dynamic allocation of 2 dimensional array in c /linux

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, multidimensional-array, allocation

I just can't figure out how to do a `malloc`. The following code just types the first 5 lines and then stops, any help would be appreciated!

```
// Read query points from query file------------------------------
double **queryPoint;

token=(char*)malloc(40);
int qp_count=0;

i=0;
qp_count=0;
while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),queryFile)!=NULL)
{
    queryPoint=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double**));
    queryPoint[qp_count]=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double*)*2);

    printf("line:%s",line); 

    token = strtok(line," ,\t");        

    queryPoint[qp_count][0]=atof(token);        
    token = strtok(NULL, " ,\t");

    printf("l[%d]=%lf \n",qp_count,queryPoint[qp_count][0]);

    queryPoint[qp_count][1]=atof(token);
    token = strtok(NULL, " ,\t");
    printf("l[%d]=%lf \n",qp_count,queryPoint[qp_count][1]);

    qp_count++;
}
```

{
This is the form of the query file

```
9.85797 5.72533
9.58711 2.09899
2.28203 7.19344
4.49096 5.50094
6.05297 1.60751
6.19901 1.52312
```

}
...
30 lines total

Comment: Please don't cast the pointer returned by malloc( ). Let the run-time handle that stuff.

Comment: The formatting is not right. token has no type specification, as well as i. Another problem deduced from the code is that you don't know in advance how many lines your two dimensional array will have. I don't know what you want or need to do. Two dimensional array doesn't seem to be appropriate.

Comment: An array of pointers to one-dimensional arrays is not a two-dimensional array. It's a very inefficient data structure unless you need the ability to swap rows in `O(1)` time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize at the beginning:

```
double **queryPoint = 0;
int qp_count = 0;
```

For every line call:

```
// call realloc to make the space for points larger by one element
queryPoint = realloc(queryPoint, sizeof(double*)*(qp_count+1));

// allocate space for the new point
queryPoint[qp_count] = malloc(sizeof(double)*2);

// increase the point count
qp_count++;
```

Note that you may use realloc to resize the space for lines. Also note that you should add error handling.

To free the memory you need to call:

```
for(int i=0;i<qp_count;i++)
    free(queryPoint[i]);

free(queryPoint);
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked fine !! I will add some error handling, you kick ass! And this site too, thanks all!

Answer (score 4):

```
queryPoint=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double**));
queryPoint[qp_count]=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double*)*2);
```

You've clearly got yourself confused with casting, sizes and various other properties of `malloc` so let's start with the syntax of a proper malloc.

Firstly, in C it is unnecessary to cast the result of the malloc operation as it always returns a pointer - the type of a pointer refers to the type of the pointed data, rather than the pointer itself, which will always be the size of a register. In C++, however, it is mandated to cast it.

Now, the general syntax of a malloc is this:

```
TYPE* pointer = malloc(n * sizeof(TYPE));
```

Where `TYPE` is some type. The `sizeof` should always be one level of indirection less than the pointer to which you're allocating. (So `TYPE**` give you a malloc of `TYPE*`). n is the number of blocks of this size to allocate, so if you want to allocate 100 doubles, that's what `n` is.

In any case, you have declared `double** queryPoint;` so your first malloc should be:

```
queryPoint = (double**) malloc(some_size*sizeof(double*));
```

This gives us an array of pointers of size `some_size`. Just like any other array, you can `realloc` this as you need to, although pre-determining the amount is probably ideal. Then, for each line you wish to allocate, you simply pick an offset from `queryPoint` and allocate an array of doubles to which that particular pointer points, like so:

```
queryPoint[i] = (double*) malloc(sizeof_this_array*sizeof(double));
```

Then, access to a specific point in the 2D array is via two subscripts: queryPoint[x][y];

As others have said, `realloc` is an option, but I advise every time you overfill the array you add a fixed amount on, or simply double what you have, as memory is (relatively) cheap and this will save a system call or six.

Now, I've talked about pointers etc so I'm going to draw an obligatory memory table so you can see what this looks like:

```
|Address      | Contents      | Comments
|-------------|---------------|-------------------------
|0x12345      | 0x20000       | double** queryPointer
| ...         | ...           | ...
|0x20000      | 0x30000       | double* queryPointer[0]
|0x20001      | 0x30016       | double* queryPointer[1]
|0x20002      | 0x30032       | double* queryPointer[2]
| ...         | ...           | ...
|0x30000      | 0183737722122 | These together make up the floating 
|0x30001      | 0183737722122 | point at double queryPointer[0][0]
|0x30002      | 0183737722122 |
| ...         | ...           | ...
|0x30016      | 0183737722122 | These together make up the floating 
|0x30017      | 0183737722122 | point at double queryPointer[0][1]
|0x30018      | 0183737722122 |
| ...         | ...           | ...
```

A pointer is just an address containing an address, so `0x12345` simply points to the start of a set of addresses from the first malloc. This is an array of pointers, so just a collection of memory addresses containing memory addresses, which point to actual values, as depicted by the `0x3***` range. Note that all address sizes, data sizes and value representations are pretty much garbage.

*That* is what is going on.

Also, don't forget to `free()` for each memory address you allocate.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `queryPoint` is each time allocated room for one pointer, which is available at index 0 (`queryPoint[0]`). You try to adress memory at `queryPoint[qp_count]`. There is no memory at this index. To fix, allocate queryPoint with as much pointers as you need to read your file.

```
int MAX_POINTER_COUNT = 10000 // whatever you choose
double** queryPoint=(double**)malloc(MAX_POINTER_COUNT * sizeof(double**));
```

Be sure not to write behind the end of the array! Doing so is a potentially exploitabele buffer overflow error. (especially if you read data supplied from the outside).

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.  `queryPoint` is basically an array of arrays.  However, each time through the loop, you replace the previous `queryPoint` pointer with a new one to a single `double*`.  What you actually want to do is grow `queryPoint` by one pointer:

```
queryPoint = (double**)realloc(queryPoint, sizeof(double*)*(qp_count+1));
```

(Note that for this to work `queryPoint` should be initialized to `NULL`.)

Also, your second allocation should be `sizeof(double)*2`, not `sizeof(double*)*2`.

Notice the pattern: inside the `malloc` (or `realloc`) we have a `sizeof(TYPE)`.  The return value is then cast to `TYPE*`.  For example:

```
p = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*n);
pp = (double**)malloc(sizeof(double*)*n);
```

Comment: Check your `realloc()`; it takes two arguments!  Also, beware leaking the previous allocation if the new one fails; never assign the result of `realloc()` directly to the variable being reallocated.

Comment: Apologies, I fixed my realloc, thanks.  Interesting point about leaking.  I never actually thought about that, and I've been programming for years.  I suspect in practice I don't use `realloc` much, (ever?) and so have never been bitten by that bug.  I just did a `man realloc`, and found Free BSD's `reallocf` is on my system to help address this issue!

Answer (score 0):

You leak the space allocated by the `token = malloc(40);` line; that's not good.

You don't show the definition of `line`.

Each time round the loop, you leak the space previously allocated to `queryPoint`.

Your casting on `queryPoint=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double**));` is wrong; `double **queryPoint;` should not be assigned a `double *`.  Opinion is split (not necessarily evenly) on whether the cast is a good idea at all.

Each time around the loop after the first, you access space out of the area allocated to `queryPoint`.

You initialize `int qp_count = 0;` and then set it to zero again with `qp_count = 0;` where one of the two assignments is sufficient.

Your second `strtok()` in the loop could be looking for newline too.

You don't check that `strtok()` found a token, either time.  You don't check that `atof()` was successful.  (Actually, it is not possible to check `atof()`; you would probably need to use `strtod()` instead.)

Answer (score 0):

You should first define more precisely what you are trying to do.

You don't know how many lines are in the file, so you don't know initially how many lines the two dimensional array must have. The initial problem/question seams bogus. A two dimensional array is not appropriate for such type of conditions.

A linked list seems more appropriate. If there are only two values per line (row) a structure might be more appropriate so that you can add the pointer to the next queryPoint pair.

Answer (score 0):

How many bytes do you expect to be allocated on this call?

```
queryPoint=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double**));
```

How many did malloc( ) actually give you?

It gave you however many bytes there are in a `void *`, probably eight on  your 32-bit machine.

What's going on here?

```
queryPoint[qp_count]=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double*)*2);
```

You're storing right back into queryPoint, overlaying the pointer that malloc( ) gave you in the immediately previous line. Is that what you intend?

Answer (score -2):

This is how you `malloc` a two-dimensional array:

```
double (*two_dim_array)[ncols] = malloc(nrows * sizeof *two_dim_array);
```

Comment: Why is this being downvoted?  It is in some ways more correct, and is legal c99.  Is it simply too terse?

Comment: If `ncols` is a constant expression (as in OP's example where it's simply 2) then this is even valid C89. But in any case, it's the correct answer for how to allocate a *two-dimensional array* as opposed to an "array of pointers to one-dimensional arrays", the latter of which looks deceptively like a two-dimensional array when you put `[i][j]` after its name...

Comment: It is too terse to be helpful.

Comment: Though a **real** `malloc` of a two dimensional array would be `double (*A)[n][m] = malloc(sizeof *A)`. Why does everybody always have the impression that 2D arrays in C have necessarily to be arrays of pointers to 1D arrays?

Comment: Indeed Jens, your answer is slightly better with regard to type, but it's less useful in a C89-restricted environment. (Mine still works if only the number of rows varies.)